# Entity Framework and inheritance filter

Tags: inheritance, entity-framework-4, where-clause

I have a first abstract Entity : Person.
Two entities inherit from Person :
Teacher and Student.

Now how can I get all students ? 
PersonSet.Where(p => p is Student) won't work, obviously, so ? What's the good practice here ?

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**OfType()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344857.aspx) method:

```
var students = PersonSet.OfType<Student>();
```